# How do I acces the element inside the second array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I got a really stupid problem I know how to do this I just can't get it to work. How do I get the element inside the second array in this example, I want the url element:

```
var_dump($friend['picture']);

array(1) {
   ["data"]=> array(2) {
       ["url"]=> string(78) "A URL" 
       ["is_silhouette"]=> bool(false) 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see an example of this in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php#example-86).  In your particular case, you can access the element using the following code:

```
$friend['picture']['data']['url']
```